# Need to find all results where the concatenation results match the concat(column1, column2)

Tags: sql, hive

I need to find results for those where the concatenated list i have matches with the `concat(car_number, penalty_date)`

```
select car_number, crn, city, rulename,dt from hive.trust.fraud_crns_consolidated_reporting  
where (select concat(car_number,penalty_date) as "Concatenation") in
('svvsvsvs25072019-08-25')
```

Results:

```
Car_number crn    city       rulename  dt 
svvsvsvs   33334  Bangalore   dd2      2019-08-25
```

Comment: SQL simply does not allow column aliases defined in the `SELECT` to be used in the corresponding `WHERE` clause.  You need to use a CTE, subquery, or repeat the expression.

Comment: I don't know if this works: did you try `where concat(car_number,penalty_date) in ('XDFDFD2019-09-01')`

Comment: Why are you using `in ('XDFDFD2019-09-01')` instead of `where concat(car_number,penalty_date) = 'XDFDFD2019-09-01'`? Unless you have more than one thing to match, the `IN` clause is not needed.

Comment: Actually i have a list of items that i need to match so thats why i have used "in"

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery like this:

```
Select * 
from
    (select car_number, crn, city, rulename,dt, concat(car_number,penalty_date) as "Concatenation"
     from hive.trust.fraud_crns_consolidated_reporting
    ) t
where t.Concatenation = 'XDFDFD2019-09-01'
```

Or use concat in where clause

```
select car_number, crn, city, rulename,dt, concat(car_number,penalty_date) as "Concatenation"
from hive.trust.fraud_crns_consolidated_reporting 
where concat(car_number,penalty_date) = 'XDFDFD2019-09-01'
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks so much!! What if i wanted to see the concat column in the results?

Comment: That column will appear in result with name "Concatation" . If you want `car_number` and `penalty_date` then simply write it in select clause and they will appear in result.

Comment: But the result is not giving me the concatenation column

Comment: It must be there in result. Can you edit the question with query that you are executing and result which you are getting?

Comment: Can you please execute the exact query as mentioned in my answer and check the result?

Comment: Yes it did work! Thanks so much! So as i understand that "t" was basically an alias for the entire subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
where concat(car_number,penalty_date) ('XDFDFD2019-09-01')
```

OR

```
select * from
(
select car_number, crn, city, rulename,dt, concat(car_number,penalty_date) as Concatenation
from hive.trust.fraud_crns_consolidated_reporting 
) s where Concatenation in ('XDFDFD2019-09-01')
```